# Why [unixODBC][Driver Manager] doesn't see sqlanywhere12 library in /opt if path in php exists

Tags: php, ubuntu, odbc, apache2, sqlanywhere

I do setting for odbcinst.ini in etc:

`[Sybase12]`

`Description=SQL Anywhere 12`

`Driver=/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so`

`Setup=/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so`

`UsageCount=1`

**`TDS_Version = 5`**
I do setting for odbc.init in etc:

`[asvioDB]`

`info for connect to DB`

`Driver=Sybase12`

Download zip file with sqlanywhere and drug and drop to opt folder in WSL with chmod 777 and after this do chmod 777 for opt folder but fith flag -R.

Do default setting for apache with **SetEnv:**

`<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName projectName

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projectName
```

SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64:/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib32
SetEnv ODBCINI /etc/odbc.ini
SetEnv SQLANY12 /opt/sqlanywhere12

```
<Directory /var/www/html/projectName>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Require all granted

</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_access.log combined
```

`

After this enable my config and disable default 000-congif and restart apache2.
add to file some text for export in etc in apache 2 in envvars

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64:/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib32:`

`export SQLANY12=/opt/sqlanywhere12`

`export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini`

sudo nano  /ect/apache2/apache2.conf in direction /var/www add permission AllowOverride All

sudo nano to etc to hosts and write 127.0.0.1 project name and change in yii2 project config files

Comment: First get program `isql` work, then standalone `php`.